# ldap oclAccess does not seem to work with pwdPolicy

Tags: openldap

I have installed ldap 2.4.3 on Ubuntu 14.04. I have configured pwdPolicy overlay and it works when the users changes his/her own password and when admin changes the password. The problem is that when admin changes the password the policies are not adhered. So, I created another account called usermanagement and added the dn to oclAccess. I can modify all fields I've tried using the usermanagement account except for userpassword.

When running ldappasswd I get `Insufficient access (50)`

This is My olcAccess:

```
olcAccess: {0}to attrs=userPassword,shadowLastChange by self write by dn="cn=admin,dc=zed,dc=com" write by dn="cn=usermanagement,dc=zed,dc=com" write by anonymous auth by * none
olcAccess: {1}to dn.base="" by * read
olcAccess: {2}to * by self write by dn="cn=admin,dc=zed,dc=com" write by dn="cn=usermanagement,dc=zed,dc=com" write by * read
```

**Edit**

I have enabled debugging and then executed `ldappasswd -H ldap://localhost -x -D "uid=luis,ou=users,dc=zed,dc=com" -W -S "uid=vixian,ou=users,dc=zed,dc=com"`. The log shows:

```
983c0f8 bdb_dn2entry("cn=passworddefault,ou=policies,dc=zed,dc=com")
5983c0f8 => bdb_entry_get: found entry: "cn=passworddefault,ou=policies,dc=zed,dc=com"
5983c0f8 bdb_entry_get: rc=0
5983c0f8 change password must use DELETE followed by ADD/REPLACE
5983c0f8 send_ldap_result: conn=1004 op=1 p=3
5983c0f8 send_ldap_result: err=50 matched="" text="Must supply old password to be changed as well as new one"
5983c0f8 send_ldap_extended: err=50 oid= len=0
5983c0f8 send_ldap_response: msgid=2 tag=120 err=50
```

I then tried to delete the userPassword using ldapmodify and it was successful but replacing or adding produced the same result permission denied.

I have updated the olcAccess following @ejp suggestion:

```
olcAccess: {0}to attrs=userPassword,shadowLastChange 
    by group/groupOfUniqueNames/uniqueMember.exact="cn=itinst,ou=groups,dc=zed,dc=com" write 
    by anonymous auth 
    by self write
olcAccess: {1}to dn.base="" by * read
olcAccess: {2}to * 
    by self write 
    by group/groupOfUniqueNames/uniqueMember.exact="cn=itinst,ou=groups,dc=zed,dc=com" write 
    by users read by anonymous search
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The problem is that when admin changes the password the policies are not adhered.

When the *managerDN* changes the password 'the policies are not adhered'. You should not use the `managerDN` for *anything.* That's the account the server runs as, and it can do anything, of course. You should define a separate `admin` account *in the DIT*, and give it the appropriate access rights, as I have for the entire `ldap admins` group in the example below.

It doesn't have anything to do with your `olcAccess`. Have a look at the documentation for how to do this properly. I have:

```
olcAccess {0}to attrs=userPassword
  by dn.base="cn=replicator,dc=verismart,dc=com,c=us" write
  by group/groupOfUniqueNames/uniqueMember.exact="cn=ldap admins,ou=groups,dc=verismartlabs,dc=com" write
  by group/groupOfUniqueNames/uniqueMember.exact="cn=applications,ou=groups,dc=verismartlabs,dc=com" write
  by anonymous auth  by self write
olcAccess {1}to dn.base=""  by * read
olcAccess {2}to *
  by self write
  by dn.base="cn=replicator,dc=verismart,dc=com,c=us" write
  by group/groupOfUniqueNames/uniqueMember.exact="cn=ldap admins,ou=groups,dc=verismartlabs,dc=com" write
  by group/groupOfUniqueNames/uniqueMember.exact="cn=applications,ou=groups,dc=verismartlabs,dc=com" write
  by users read
  by anonymous search
```

**EDIT** As you're using the `ppolicy` overlay:

1. You should use the `-e ppolicy` argument to `ldappasswd` so you can see the extended response if any.
2. The user must also use the `-a` option to `ldappasswd` to specify the old password, as suggested by the log, or `-A` to get it to prompt you for it. The change log is saying `change password must use DELETE followed by ADD/REPLACE`, which means you have to supply both the old and the new password. `ldappasswd` will send a DELETE for the old one and an ADD or a REPLACE for the new value.
3. How you get the admin to do it without knowing the old password is another question, looking ... Works for me via an application, but I've never done it via `ldappasswd`. Maybe `-e ppolicy` is the answer to that too.

**EDIT 2** It is because you have `pwdSafeModify=TRUE` in your password policy. This rather useless setting makes it impossible for administrators to reset passwords without knowing the old one, and if the old one was known there would be no need for the administrative reset at all. I have it turned off, but then all my passwords are changed only by Java code: one piece for the user himself, and another for the administrator, so I can enforce `pwdSafeModify` myself.

Comment: I have removed admin from olcAccesss; perhaps my config is misguiding by the lack of formatting but anonymous is not given write access. I have added an account in the DIT but I still get Insufficient Access.